# Is this function of a sum of indicator functions convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

let $x=x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ for $x \ge 0$,

let $I(x) =max(x_i, 0) $ for $i \in [1,n]$

$f(x) = I(c-x)a^T+I(x-c)b^T$ where $a,b,c$ are constant vectors

Is this a convex function? How is this proven?

Comment: Do you know anything about the signs of the elements of $a, b$? Also, are you using column vectors or row vectors? (it seems like all your vectors are row vectors)

Comment: the elements of a,b,c are all > 0. I'm using row vectors. x-c will contain some positive elements and some negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $f$ is a convex function. You just need to know some some basic properties that imply convexity:

- Linear and convex functions are convex.
- The maximum of convex functions is convex.
- The composition of a convex function with an affine map is convex.
- Nonnegative linear combinations of convex functions are convex.

From that we have:

- The functions $x_i$ and $0$ are convex.
- The components of $I(x)$, namely $\max(x_i,0)$ are convex.
- The components of $I(c-x)$ and $I(x-c)$ are convex.
- The nonnegative combinations $I(c-x)a^T$ and $I(x-c)b^T$ are convex, provided $a,b\ge0$. Likewise $f$ itself is convex.

Comment: are negative linear combinations of convex functions convex? Is $()=(−)^T -(−)^ $convex?

Comment: In general, no. Though they can be in some cases. It's just like with positive functions. Sums of positive functions are positive, but differences of positive functions are not positive in general.

Comment: how can I discern if this particular negative linear combination is convex?

Comment: I guess in this particular case, it reduces to sum of several 1-dimensional functions, and $a \max(c-x,0)-b \max(x-c,0)$ will be convex if $b \le a$.